# Conditionally pushing to an array with spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I am pushing elements to an array based on a condition as explained here http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html

```
const arr = [
  ...(cond ? ['a'] : []),
  'b',
];
```

Now, this works fine, but when I try

```
const arr = [
  ...(cond && ['a']),
  'b',
];
```

instead, it stops working.

I would like to know why it's not working anymore, and if there is a way to conditionally push using spread operator and && instead of ?.

Thank you

Comment: please add the value of `cond`.

Comment: In the second example, if `cond` evaluates to false, the expression evaluates to `false` and you end up with `...false` instead of `...[]` therefore throwing an error.

Comment: @NinaScholz cond is a condition, and as such, may be true or false

Comment: @Miguel in the case I am using to test particulary it evaluates to true, and it does not add "a" to the array. Either way, do you know to fix this?

Comment: @user3808307 you can try in the console: `[...(true && ['a'])]` gives `['a']` but `[...(false && ['a'])]` yield a `TypeError`.

Comment: yes, @SébastienDeprez, you are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible, because all iterable objects are truthy.

If `cond` is falsey, you have a value which is not spreadable by [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)

> The built-in types with a @@iterator method are:
>
> - [`Array.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)
> - [`TypedArray.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/@@iterator)
> - [`String.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator)
> - [`Map.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator)
> - [`Set.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator)

```js
var cond = false;

const arr = [
  ...(cond && ['a']),  // throws error, function expected
  'b',
];

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: with conditional operator `?:`, you supply an (empty) array which is spreadable/iterable. it works like a neutral element here.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, it's possible. <sub>But maybe that's an overkill <sub>that performs worse and decreases the readability.</sub></sub>

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push(...[false && 'nope'].filter(v => v));
arr.push(...[true && 'yep'].filter(v => v));
arr.push(...[false && 'no', true && 'yes'].filter(v => v));
    
console.info(arr);
```

As @Nina Scholz [indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783397/2013580) an iterable is required for spread operator to work. By using a second array (which may be empty) we can eventually reach the following state (`arr.push()`).

Comment: Up vote because made me laugh and fixed my issue lol